# Javascript dependencies include guards

Tags: javascript

Hello I playing with javascript and I have the following situation

I have defined a `point` class. I have defined an `edge` class which depends on `point` and a `triangle` class which depends both on `point` and `edge`. How do I ensure that those classes are loaded correctly?

I use them as follows:

```
<script src="point.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="edge.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="triangle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="utils.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

the `utils.js` file are some generic utility functions that uses all of the above classes.
My problem is that I cannot tell the `triangle` class for example, that the `point` and `edge` classes are defined. My code just assumes them to be defined somewhere or else it crashes burning down. Is there a simple `#include` style mechanism for javascript?

For example I would like to just use the `triangle` class which internally should somehow find about its dependencies and load them automagically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For example I would like to just use the `triangle` class which internally should somehow find about its dependencies and load them automagically

You're in luck! Tools like [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) exist specifically for this purpose, and do it very well. Take a look at RequireJS's [Get Started](http://requirejs.org/docs/start.html) docs and the [many available tutorials](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=requirejs%20tutorial). There are other, similar tools like [Browserify](http://browserify.org/), but RequireJS is a good place to start and has lots of documentation and users.

Comment: Wow this sucks. I cannot believe that javascript allows you to have objects but does not allow you to define dependencies between them. Anyways, this solves the problem ==  accepted.

Comment: If you were around when JavaScript debuted in 1996 you would not be surprised at all. Happily, ES6 will have module support baked in. You can [read about it here](http://eviltrout.com/2014/05/03/getting-started-with-es6.html), which includes links on how to use the draft syntax (with a build script) today.