# Proper way to add JavaScript include guard

Tags: javascript, include

In the C programming language, there's an include guard which prevents the same header file being included twice:

```
#ifndef GRANDPARENT_H
#define GRANDPARENT_H

struct foo {
    int member;
};

#endif /* GRANDPARENT_H */
```

In web pages, JavaScript is often used as a header file, too. Sometimes a developer can mistakenly include the same file twice, causing bugs that are hard to debug (examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6732163/418966)).

The proper way to prevent multiple includes of the same file should be an include guard. But what is the proper way to add such a guard to a JavaScript file so that it works without polluting namespace, breaking other script and other unwanted behavior?

---

This question is not a duplicate of [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25142935/javascript-dependencies-include-guards), which doesn't talk about the potential problems of using such a guard. Furthermore, it points to another library, while a lightweight, inline solution would be much more welcome.

Comment: *"In web pages, JavaScript is often used as a header file, too."* – That statement makes little sense…!?

Comment: @deceze If you write JavaScript inside a `<script>` element within `<body>`, in that case, I'm wondering if you can still call it a *header* file. I'm not really into this style but some people do it.

Comment: *Header files*, as in  C .h files, are something entirely different than putting a `script` element into an HTML `<head>` element.

Answer (score 1):

The most modular, reusable and "safe" method is simply that including a file shouldn't *do* anything besides defining some objects/classes/names. If you include a file multiple times, it simply overwrites the previous definition. You then have *one* entry point somewhere which explicitly starts the code, e.g.:

```
<body onload="myscript.foo()">
```

The same goes for includes within Javascript (typically needing a build/bundle system):

```
import foo from 'bar';
const foo = require('bar');

foo();
```